# Load 2 pages upon button click BUT show only 1 page

Tags: javascript, html

I need to load 2 pages upon button click, but ONLY ONE page should actually open:
1) Page one is the actual page that the button links to and should load on screen. I do not control this page so cannot place any conversion tracking pixels on this one.
2) Page two is more like a 'Thank You' page so that I can place conversion pixels there. BUt I do not want to actually show this page (in a popup or in a browser).

I'm using this code, but it opens both windows:

```js
<p><a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com');
    window.open('http://yahoo.com');">Click to open Google and Yahoo</a></p>
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You misunderstood how SO works. We do not write up code to users, we help with written code. Do some research, make an effort of your own and come back if you can't make it work. Please read [ask] and [help/on-topic] for more info on what and how to post a question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better tying the conversion somehow to the actual button click, if that's possible (fire a JS event to track a conversion when the button is clicked, in addition to opening the link).

```
<p><a href="#"  onclick="window.open('http://google.com'); someTrackingFunction()";">Click to open Google and track this conversion</a></p>
```

Otherwise, you could maybe try directing the link to the blank page with the tracking pixel, which then has a redirect tied to it (so it would briefly load the tracking pixel, you would get the conversion info, and then it would push the user to the linked page).

I can't really say anything specific without some code examples or more info on what you're hoping to do.